# Multiple TinyMCE instances on single page dosent give the value after form submit

Tags: cakephp, post, tinymce

I am using multiple tinyMCE editors in my CakePHP application on single page. 
This is a QnA application.

My code is like this
**For question :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode:"textareas",
        theme:"simple"
    });

</script>
<form action="/qna/questions/add" class="innerForm" id="QuestionViewForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <input name="data[Question][title]" placeholder="Please enter the title of your question" id="title"
           class="span7 focusBlur" maxlength="255" type="text">
    <textarea name="data[Question][description]" id="description" class="span7 questionDescription" div="false"
              rows="5">Please enter
        description</textarea>
    <input class="btn blueBtn" type="submit" value="Add Your Question" data-original-title="">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="link cancel" id="cancel" data-original-title="">Cancel</a>

</form>
```

**For answer :**

```
<form action="/qna/answers/add" class="innerForm" id="AnswerForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
    <textarea name="data[Answer][answer]" id="answer" class="span7 questionDescription" div="false"  rows="5">Please enter answer</textarea>
    <input class="btn blueBtn" type="submit" value="Add Your Question" data-original-title="">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="link cancel" id="cancel" data-original-title="">Cancel</a>
```

But whenever I submit a question form, It give me the value in the text area, it skips the value in the tinyMCE.

Output is :

```
Array
(
[Question] => Array
    (
        [resource_id] => 1003
        [type] => 0
        [title] => This is my question
        [description] => Please enter description
    )
)
```

I typed the different description for question :(

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: This link might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574894/cakephp-tinymcehelper-helper-error-method-tinymcehelper-name-does-not-exis. and http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/TommyO/2006/11/08/using-tinymce-with-cakephp-and-ajax

Comment: Thanks, Arun.. I got the issue, i was using ajax to load the QnA by scroll pagination & again i added the same tinymce object in that CTP so it was re-initializing the editors. When i removed the double initialization the issue ge resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/TommyO/2006/11/08/using-tinymce-with-cakephp-and-ajax) might help you to achieve the same.

[This problem solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574894/cakephp-tinymcehelper-helper-error-method-tinymcehelper-name-does-not-exis) might also help you to resolve the errors you are getting.